# Linux Hydra issue - random correct password success

Tags: attacks, penetration-test, http, brute-force

I have an issue with Hydra when I use it.  I have tried the same command lines given in guides directly supported by the Damn Vulnerable Web Application (DVWA) v1.8.

Ok so.. here is my attempt output...

```
root@kali:~# hydra 192.168.1.2 -l admin -P /wordlists/500-worst-passwords.txt
http-get-form "/DVWA-1.0.8/vulnerabilities/brute/index.php:username=^USER^&
password=^PASS^&submit=Login:Username and/or password incorrect." -f

Hydra v7.3 (c)2012 by van Hauser/THC & David Maciejak - for legal purposes only

Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2013-09-06 05:18:12
[DATA] 16 tasks, 1 server, 500 login tries (l:1/p:500), ~31 tries per task
[DATA] attacking service http-get-form on port 80
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.2   login: admin   password: shadow
[STATUS] attack finished for 192.168.1.2 (valid pair found)
1 of 1 target successfuly completed, 1 valid password found
Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) finished at 2013-09-06 05:18:12
```

Yes, its true that the HTML form method is GET. :O)

Ok so, regardless how many times I run the command I get different answers.. like..

Attempt 1

```
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.2   login: admin   password: 101193
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.2   login: admin   password: horse
```

Attempt 2

```
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.2   login: admin   password: carhorn
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.2   login: admin   password: shadowfox
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.2   login: admin   password: multible
```

UPDATE!!!!

```
hydra 192.168.1.2 -l admin -P /wordlists/500-worst-passwords.txt http-get-form 
"/DVWA-1.0.8/vulnerabilities/brute/index.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&
submit=Login:Username and/or password incorrect.:H=Cookie: security=high;
PHPSESSID=jtujthkeh08foqfomph232rp77"
```

I tried to add the cookie phpsession id aswell.  I also tried to put in the:

```
-t <tasks>
```

So far I have no success.

Comment: I may add that, the password file that use do contain the correct password.  I think its about line 20 or so its found in the file.

Comment: hydra scans for "Username and/or password incorrect" to detect failed attempts in the answer. if this is not found, for whatever reasons, if thinx that login is OK.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the output text is correct in my case :-).  The output text the application makes is "Username and/or password incorrect."

Comment: Let me add that i tried to set different failure attempts in aswell, as in parts of the failed text.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37020/why-does-hydra-return-16-valid-passwords-when-none-are-valid?rq=1 .... I tried this aswell.. added the session ID and all.. dident work for me.

Comment: the output-text is correct, thats not what i wanted to say. what i wanted to say is: what happens if the response is empty? or your server is overloaded and doesnt respond / respond with 403? i see the issue here with hydra, not beeing able to detect false positives. maybe you limit the concurrent-number of tests until you get valid results

Comment: A very good suggestion.  However i think i discovered that i need to provide the session of the site, because i am logged in on it.  But i already tried that, and it dident work.  I will also try your suggestion in a bundle of what i already discovered :-)

Comment: I updated my question with some of the newest tries.

Comment: I cant get it to work properly.  Its still the same.  I tried adding the session, fixing the amounts og tasks.  I even double checked on the error message that the form will give.  Everything so far is 100% ok.  So what did i miss out on? :)

Comment: Arent you supposed to target the script given in "<form action="verify.php">"?