# Hydra gives wrong answers

Tags: web-application, brute-force, hydra

Problem: Hydra keeps giving me incorrect passwords every time.
I'm using brute-force via Hydra to guess the correct password on a certain website.

First of all I used BurpSuite to intercept the page request:

```
POST /abcdefg/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:2000 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0 Iceweasel/22.0 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Referer: http://localhost:2000/abcdefg/ Connection: keep-alive Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Length: 23 

usr=admin&pass=password
```

I am using these parameters for the command-line:

```
hydra -f -v -V 127.0.0.1 -s 2000 http-post-form -l admin -P /documents/pass.txt "/abcdefg/:pass=^PASS^:incorrect password"
```

1. Host = `127.0.0.1` ( I know I can also try with `localhost`)
2. Port = `2000` (My local computer is listening for HTTP at port 2000)
3. Method = `http-post-form`
4. URL = `/abcdefg/`
5. Form parameters = `pass=^PASS^`
6. Failure response = `incorrect password`. When I click *submit*, the page reloads with the same URL, but with only the text 'incorrect password' on screen.
7. User = `admin`
8. Password file = `pass.txt`

The page source of the login page:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Login</title>
</head>
        <form action="./" method="post">
        username <input type="text" name="usr"></br>
        password <input type="password" name="pass"></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
</html>
```

The page source of the 'incorrect password' page:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Login</title>
</head>

<br>incorrect password
```

Please take a look at all the parameters to make sure I am using the right commands.

I have also taken a look at this question:  [Why does Hydra return 16 valid passwords when none are valid?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37020/why-does-hydra-return-16-valid-passwords-when-none-are-valid) which suggests checking the page cookies, but the webpage I'm trying to brute force into does not use cookies, so I think that is irrelevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't

`"/abcdefg/:pass=^PASS^:incorrect password"`
 be set to

`"/:usr=^USER^&pass=^PASS^:incorrect password"`

to match your form action as `<form action="./"` and username input as `<input type="text" name="usr">`?

Comment: Oh, I thought it's okay to leave that one out since I want Hydra to only test the password field, but thinking again, it makes sense to include the use field.
 
Isn't the format supposed to be 
`"URL_of_the_page:input fields:failure message"`?

I used 
`"/abcdefg/:usr=^USER^&pass=^PASS^:incorrect password"`
This seems to do the trick! Thanks!